# How to attach this tap cover?

Tags: sink, taps

The cover of my bathroom's tap always goes away. I find the system quite silly because you have to remove it to access the screw inside if necessary yet it's glued on it!

Anyway what solution/product could I use so that the cover stop going away all the time?

[image]
[image]

Comment: My guess is that someone glued it on rather than the manufacturer. At this point the aggravation of it continuing to come off, and its damaged looking condition would probably best be resolved by replacing it with a new one.  Plus with the available choices, you can select the type you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also a bad design because any water that gets in there pools.  For that reason I would "glue" it on with a basic latex caulk.  When you need to service the tap you'll have to cut out the caulk.